# Is there an easier way to cast a struct as a pointer to a struct

Tags: c

I have a unit test program i wrote to catch errors in the functions of an open source project before the initial compilation. All of the functions i need to test return a pointer to a struct(in this case `bn_poly`) while my variable is NOT a pointer. I know there must be an easier solution to this problem but after a bit of googling i came up with nothing, here is what i'm currently doing

```
/* only relevant part of code */
struct *bn_poly poly_summ;
unsigned i
poly_summ = (struct bn_poly*)bu_malloc(sizeof(struct bn_poly),"sum");
/* test multiplication and begin checking data */
*poly_summ = bn_poly_mul(&poly_summ,poly_eqn,poly_mul);
/* bn_poly returns a pointer to bn_poly, so i have to declare
 * a temporary pointer to find the value. Is this the only way
 * or is there a type cast method i am missing?
 */
```

---

what i would like to be able to do:

```
struct bn_poly poly_summ;
poly_summ = (somethingToConvertReturnVal)bn_poly_mul(&poly_summ,poly_eqn,poly_mul);
/* no memory allocation needed! */
```

Comment: In my experience you should avoid casting - it usually indicates that you are doing something that the compiler cannot figure out. AKA maybe an error in your code.

Comment: Your question just looks very confused, and I am not sure that the answer you accepted will provide you what you need. From the names of the functions you are using I'd guess that your functions don't just return an arbitrary pointer, but one of the arguments that is at the same time used to return the result. In that case just use that pointer, or the original variable that you used to pass into the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little bit confused regarding what your question is But here's what i know about "casting" pointers.

- the `&` symbol is the reference symbol, so  `&x` gives you the address of x, or a pointer which points to x
- the `*` symbol is the deference symbol, so suppose `x` is a pointer, `*x` gives you the value `x` points to

in your case, i think you want

```
struct bn_poly poly_summ;
poly_summ = *(bn_poly_mul(/*params*/));
```

as an additional note, by the looks of it, `bn_poly_mul` looks like it already allocates your struct and puts it on the heap.  You don't even need to allocate it, in-fact doing so would result in a memory leak

---

Also, the fact that the first parameter of `bn_poly_mul` is `&poly_summ` is a little bit off-putting to me, so I'd have to see the function to know for sure

Comment: i dont want to have to allocate memory just for a pointer in `poly_sum`, i want some way of assigning a pointer to struct return value to a non pointer variable.

Comment: will this deference the function pointer and give me the value? EDIT: bn_poly_mul does not, i have access to the function source and it requires all variables to be allocated.

Comment: @Need4Sleep  if the pointer actually references a value then the dereference operator will give you that value